# Microphone input RMS measurement on Android device

Tags: android, kotlin, audio-recording, adc, rms

I want to measure the RMS value of the input audio signal over periods of 100-200 ms on an Android device without recording the audio to a file. This is not to measure the noise level, I only need the RMS value of the ADC. Please suggest an appropriate approach. Should I look into the AudioRecord class, the Oboe library or something completely different? I am an amateur with very basic Android/Kotlin knowledge. Thank you!)

I tried to find examples of Kotlin code regarding recording audio from a microphone to a byte array, but I did not succeed.